In android studio menu there is no menu for Xcode
There is no menu to open directly IOS folder in Xcode after upgrade to new version while working in Flutter project. How can I get this menu again? How can I fix it?
As first, there is a menu called flutter and I can open IOS folder in Xcode by selecting that. Now it is disappear.


What version of Android Studio are you using? Also, what options do you see in the Open In choice?

My android studio version is Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1. In previous version there is a menu called "Flutter" at the end of the menu drop down.

I have the same issue with AS Koala - the "flutter" context menu item that used to show when right clicking the ios folder (which then opened - open in xcode) is not showing any more. I end up right clicking the xcodeworkspace > open in finder > right click the xcodeworkspace and open in xcode.

In addition to the above - the Tools menu (top of screen) in AS also has the Flutter>open in xcode option

Yep, I suppose AS change a little bit that setting. Thanks.
